# parsing xml file with PHP 5?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

simply i use

```
simplexml_load_file
```

to parse xml file

when i used it to parse the file it works just great and return all of the file content

```
<?php
//$homepage = file_get_contents('');
$x = simplexml_load_file('http://www.metacafe.com/api/videos?vq=sexy&max-results=50');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($x);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

the out put just fine

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
            [source] => Metacafe
        )

    [title] => Metacafe
    [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/tags/sexy/
            [image] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [url] => http://s.mcstatic.com/Images/MCLogo4RSS.jpg
                    [link] => http://www.metacafe.com
                    [title] => Metacafe
                    [height] => 65
                    [width] => 229
                )

            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id] => 9310776
                            [author] => ORLIK MUSCLE VIDEO
                            [title] => Muscle Worship. MEET: 18 Y.o. Vlad
                            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/9310776/muscle_worship_meet_18_y_o_vlad/
                            [rank] => 4.33
                            [category] => Sports
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [guid] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/9310776/muscle_worship_meet_18_y_o_vlad/
                            [pubDate] => 01-Nov-12 +0000
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id] => yt-RU2yJxjxMtw
                            [author] => Metacafe Affiliate U
                            [title] => 10 Minute Intense Sexy Bikini ABS WORKOUT!! TRY IT!!
                            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/yt-RU2yJxjxMtw/10_minute_intense_sexy_bikini_abs_workout_try_it/
                            [rank] => 4.33
                            [category] => How To
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [guid] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/yt-RU2yJxjxMtw/10_minute_intense_sexy_bikini_abs_workout_try_it/
                            [pubDate] => 30-Oct-12 +0000
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id] => 9296344
                            [author] => Sonia Wari
                            [title] => Arab Real Hot Girl Desi Video
                            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/9296344/arab_real_hot_girl_desi_video/
                            [rank] => 4.33
                            [category] => Entertainment
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [guid] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/9296344/arab_real_hot_girl_desi_video/
                            [pubDate] => 28-Oct-12 +0000
                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id] => 9299266
                            [author] => lehren.tv
                            [title] => Sherlyn Chopra In 3D Kamasutra
                            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/9299266/sherlyn_chopra_in_3d_kamasutra/
                            [rank] => 4.22
                            [category] => Entertainment
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [guid] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/9299266/sherlyn_chopra_in_3d_kamasutra/
                            [pubDate] => 29-Oct-12 +0000
                        )

                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id] => cb-r3B4NEf5A8sw
                            [author] => CBS
                            [title] => Can the New Dart Give Dodge a Sexy Italian Accent? CNET On Cars, Episode 5
                            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/cb-r3B4NEf5A8sw/can_the_new_dart_give_dodge_a_sexy_italian_accent_cnet_on_cars_episode_5/
                            [rank] => 4.00
                            [category] => Entertainment
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [guid] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/cb-r3B4NEf5A8sw/can_the_new_dart_give_dodge_a_sexy_italian_accent_cnet_on_cars_episode_5/
                            [pubDate] => 30-Oct-12 +0000
                        )

                    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [id] => cb-jZx26n5Iweg1
                            [author] => CBS
                            [title] => The Young and the Restless - 10/30/2012 Sneak Peek - Season 40
                            [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/cb-jZx26n5Iweg1/the_young_and_the_restless_10_30_2012_sneak_peek_season_40/
                            [rank] => 4.00
                            [category] => Entertainment
                            [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                )

                            [guid] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/cb-jZx26n5Iweg1/the_young_and_the_restless_10_30_2012_sneak_peek_season_40/
                            [pubDate] => 30-Oct-12 +0000
                        )


                )

        )

)
```

problem is just start when i tried to print the item array only

```
<?php
//$homepage = file_get_contents('');
$x = simplexml_load_file('http://www.metacafe.com/api/videos?vq=sexy&max-results=50');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($x->channel->item);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

this one only getting the first object of the item array not the whole array

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => 9310776
    [author] => ORLIK MUSCLE VIDEO
    [title] => Muscle Worship. MEET: 18 Y.o. Vlad
    [link] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/9310776/muscle_worship_meet_18_y_o_vlad/
    [rank] => 4.33
    [category] => Sports
    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [guid] => http://www.metacafe.com/watch/9310776/muscle_worship_meet_18_y_o_vlad/
    [pubDate] => 01-Nov-12 +0000
)
```

what i need to do is to retrieve the whole objects of the item array

Comment: See: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic - *Example #4 Accessing non-unique elements in SimpleXML*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
//$homepage = file_get_contents('');
$x = simplexml_load_file('http://www.metacafe.com/api/videos?vq=sexy&max-results=50');
echo "<pre>";
foreach($x->channel->item as $key=>$value){
    print_r($value);
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Just make it in foraech loop ?